# Change the version name of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

So I'm tuning up my computer a little, I created a batch script that changes the lockscreen wallpaper every fifteen minutes, but my lockscreen isn't perfect yet.

As it says "Windows 7 Ultimate", it's not what I want it to be. How would I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is a picture in the file `basebrd.dll` from the folder `C:\Windows\Branding\Basebrd`. So you must use a Resource Hacker tool to edit the resource.

Comment: Oh nice! So I can just replace the pics and it's done?

Comment: The text itself is located there but the picture can be changed to whatever you like. They are separate entities.

Comment: yes, you can change this to what ever you want.